# How to save and transpose a range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro where I open a textfile to copy and transpose several columns into my worksheet. As it is now this actually works. However, as I am right now opening the textfile, copying a column, going back to my original worksheet pasting and transposing the data, then switching back and forward between the two sheets until all relevant columns have been copied I figured it could probably be optimized if I understood VBA a little better.

So my question is if I can save the column data as ranges instead and then copying it all at once and pasting and transposing it all at once as well?

Or will this not have any impact on the speed of my macro?

Also, as I am actually opening many textfiles (open one, close it, open the next, close it, etc) is it possible to overwrite a range when a new textfile has been opened?

I have shown an example of my code below hope you can make sense of it:

'First Selection to be copied
ActiveSheet.Cells(RowTemp + 1, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

```
Selection.Copy

'Go back to original sheet

Windows(Left(f, Len(f))).Activate

'Paste and Transpose Data

If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value) = True Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=True

            ActiveSheet.Cells(4 + 5 + Range("A2").Value, 1).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
             Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=True
End If

'Copy 2nd set of Data
         Windows(Left(z, Len(z))).Activate
         Range("B1").Select

         Selection.End(xlDown).Select
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
         Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
         Selection.Copy

         Windows(Left(f, Len(f))).Activate

'Paste and Transpose 2. set of data

        If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 2).Value) = True Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 2).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=True

            ActiveSheet.Cells(5 + 5 + Range("A2").Value, 2).Select
             Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=True
        End If
```

Comment: Since this code is working, I would suggest placing it on SO's Sister Site CodeReview

Comment: Hi Zack, thanks for the comment. I did not know about this site. I will post there instead :)